# select Start date and End date i want to count each day of week and insert data day wise in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceNvE.png)

i want insert data day wise as select start date and end date.
i am count only week of day using following code

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-11-17');

$end = new DateTime('2017-06-10');

$days = $start->diff($end, true)->days;

$monday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 1);

$tuesday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 2);

$wednesday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 3);

$thursday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 4);

$friday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 5);

$saturday = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 6);

$sundays = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 7);
```

Comment: The question is confusing. Can you please clarify what is your query and your progress so far?

Comment: for example - start date 2017-02-14 and end date 2017-02-28 so I want to insert data between this date in this date two Monday so in database two entry create of Monday with a specific date.

Comment: if i understand your question you want to get the count of mondays between 2 date

Comment: yes now i want condition for insert data as per count monday

Comment: I Have Already Created a service to get days : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40959139/7226219

Answer (score 0):

$sundays = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 <= 7);