# How to Calculate the weeks within a given period-Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Can someone help me with this please. Trying to calculate week dates within a  period entered by the user.  How would I go about that? I have this thus far

```
$interval=new DateInterval('P6D');
        $period = new DatePeriod($begindate,$interval,$enddate);


     foreach($period as $date){
     echo $date->format("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
    }

    if ($period){

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

2017/08/06
2017/08/12
2017/08/18 The first two outputs are ok but  rather than 2017/08/18, I would like 2017/08/13 2017/08/19 and even though they are in the database its still giving the error message that it is not there

Comment: you can try this approche https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959139/7226219

Comment: don't understand fully that approach

Answer (score 0):

You could itarate dates with [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class

UPD

get all sundays

```
$start = new DateTime('2018-08-06');
$end   = new DateTime('2018-09-06');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('7 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d') . '<br>';
}
```

Your question about the dates or about the search in the database? Please specify

Comment: Could you give me an example

Comment: Updated my question could you help me with this problem now

Comment: Hey @artemiuz still haven't figured out the answer for this question, Can you assist me please

Comment: It is both about the search and dates

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$firstDayOfWeek = $dateTime->modify('Monday this week');
$lastDayOfWeek = $dateTime->modify('Sunday this week');
```

Comment: I have edited my question with what I have. Can you help me to edit it to have that